# Is there is a way to read/write on a USB port using C++?(windows forms application)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, usb

I am kinda new to C++. Is there is a library or function that can be used to send or receive data through USB Port?

The format I need for sending the function would be something like this:

```
Write_Ex(Product ID,Vendor ID,Data);
```

I am using Windows form application using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: What kind of device are you going to talk to?

Comment: Then, if you can define the protocol it uses, may be [USB serial class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_communications_device_class) could do?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at WinUSB. Or, if the device has FTDI interface, there's libftdi.